# Setting anacron on Mac - Shell Scripting

Tags: terminal, bash, script, cron

I set cron to run script every day using `env EDITOR=nano crontab -e` where I wrote something like this `@daily path/to/sript.script`.

Now I want to use *anacron* to be sure that script is going to be run when I log in if I was logged off at the time when it was scheduled. But I am not sure where to specify that.

I tried something like `env EDITOR=nano anacron -e` but that didn't work. Also, strange is that man anacron doesn't provide anything. I get this: "No manual entry for anacron"

Comment: `anacron` is not an installed utility in OS X.  Scheduled Tasks are handled by `launchd`, `cron` has been depreciated in OS X. You can also add an app/script to the User's Login Items too.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?  At the time the script is supposed to run, is your computer powered on and you just logged off or is the computer powered off?

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys. @Allan I want to be sure that script will run as soon as possible, even if I was logged off or my computer was powered off at the time the script is supposed to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X does not provide anacron.